# Projectivization of cokernel of 2-term-Koszul-like morphism depends only on certain simple data?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-morphisms

Let $X$ be a scheme and $D \subset X$ an effective Cartier divisor on $X$. For any line bundle ${\mathcal L} \in \mathrm{Pic}(X)$ and any global section $s \in \Gamma(X,{\mathcal L})$, define
$$ Y({\mathcal L},s):=\mathrm{Proj}_X\mathrm{Sym}\mathrm{Coker} \left( {\mathcal O}_X \xrightarrow{t \mapsto ts \oplus t} {\mathcal L} \oplus {\mathcal O}_X(D)\right). $$
**Question.** Is it true that $Y({\mathcal L},s)$ depends only on ${\mathcal L}|_D$ and $s|_D$?

Specifically, if ${\mathcal L}' \in \mathrm{Pic}(X)$, $s \in \Gamma(X,{\mathcal L}')$, and $\phi:{\mathcal L}|_D \simeq {\mathcal L}'|_D$ is an isomorphism such that $\phi(s|_D) = s'|_D$, is it true that there exists a (canonical) isomorphism $Y({\mathcal L},s) \simeq Y({\mathcal L}',s')$ compatible with the projections to $X$?

*Comments.*

Of course, the point is that in many cases $Y({\mathcal L},s)$ is just the blowup of the vanishing locus of $s|_D$, but not always. I would like to know the answer to my question even in cases when this is not true -- so I might be happy with certain additional assumptions if they're necessary but certainly not assumptions which imply this.

I realize that this has to be rather routine, but I am becoming confused and frustrated by it, and wondering if I am missing something obvious. Perhaps someone could enlighten me?